# How to use shibboleth instance(s) to protect 2 domains

Tags: single-sign-on, shibboleth

I am implementing a typical classical SSO between 2 websites, on 2 different domains. One website (let's call it site1) is developed and hosted by a partner, the second website (let's call it site2) is developed and hosted by me.
I use the partner ADFS as an Idp.

I installed and configured Shibboleth SP3 to manage the authentication on site2: when I try to access site2, I am correctly redirected to the ADFS and it works.

My concern is, the end-user will authenticate to site1 first, then along the way access site2, and we don't want him to authenticate again.

I have few questions about this, how I don't know how to proceed:
- do I need the same instance of Shibboleth SP3 to manage authentication on both sites, to manage the cookie / headers, or can I use different instances (in that case, I would use Shibboleth for site2, and the partner will use another SP for site1)
- how to manage the redirection from site1 to site2 ? Can it be a request.redirect? Should site1 send a post or get request, with specific parameters?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

If the partner is hosting site1, they should be running Shibboleth on that instance, and integrate with the IdP the same as you on your instance running site2.

The whole purpose of SSO is that they don't need to re-auth. i.e. User visits site1, redirected to login on ADFS, auth (user is picking up IdP session), redirected back to site1 which validates the auth token (SAML assertion) and shows them the content.

Now, when they are pushed to site2 (by whatever means), site2 fires off the authnrequest to the ADFS server as a redirect with the user, but this time the user **already has** the ADFS session, so the ADFS server just issues the SAMLResponse. They don't make the user log back in.

This is only because both SPs are integrated with the same IdP.

You can redirect the users around however they want in this instance... but it means running instances of Shibboleth on both web servers. If you *really* wanted to only use one Shibboleth instance, you could create a SAML broker, where one webserver brokers the SAML assertion on behalf of another, but that's kind of silly. Easier to just run to Shib installs when it's two disparate servers.

If both sites live on the same server, you can do the same thing, basically... each site is a separate host on on the webserver, and you just need to configure each site (one as a default, and another as an Application Override) though you probably don't even have to go that far TBH. You'd only need to have separate ApplicationOverrides if you wish to, say, integrate site 1 with IdP_A and IdP_B, but site 2 with IdP_A and IdP_C. See: https://wiki.library.ucsf.edu/display/IAM/Steps+to+configure+multiple+context+in+Shib+SP

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly the link I was looking for. I must say that the official documentation seriously lacks of concrete usecases.